# How can you dynamically build router-links in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to do the following in Vue.js

```
     <table>
        <tr v-for="item in messages">
            <td><router-link to="'/user/' + item.id">{{ item.name }}</router-link></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

My messages property has an array of objects in it. Each object has an id property, which I want to be appended on to my to attribute. So if I had two items in the messages array with ids of 1 and 2, I would expect to get something like this:

```
     <table>
        <tr v-for="item in messages">
            <td><router-link to="/user/1">{{ item.name }}</router-link></td>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="item in messages">
            <td><router-link to="/user/2">{{ item.name }}</router-link></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I also tried putting doing {{ message.id }}, but that gives me an interpolation error. How can I get this to render the actual value for message.id in the "to" attribute? The item.name attribute renders as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `v-bind:` before `to`

```
<table>
    <tr v-for="item in messages">
        <td><router-link v-bind:to="'/user/' + item.id">{{ item.name }}</router-link></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Without `v-bind:` you're literally using `'user' + item.id` as value.
For more clarification check [this docs section](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Literal-vs-Dynamic)