# Setting the router-link to attribute with component data in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

How to inject component data in `<router-link to="...">`? Sample:

```
var data = {files: [{name: "test", path: "/test"}]};

var component = {
    data: function() {
        return data
    },
    template: '<ul class="files"><li v-for="file in files"><router-link to="{{ file.path }}">{{ file.name }}</router-link></li></ul>',
    created: function() {...}
};
```

In this sample the output is `<li><a href="#/{{ file.path }} ">test</a></li>`. How do I get `/test` instead of `#/{{ file.path }}`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you dynamically build router-links in Vue.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474129/how-can-you-dynamically-build-router-links-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong syntax, You just need to use [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) as follows:

```
template: '<ul class="files"><li v-for="file in files"><router-link v-bind:to="file.path">{{ file.name }}</router-link></li></ul>',
```

or in short:

```
template: '<ul class="files"><li v-for="file in files"><router-link :to="file.path">{{ file.name }}</router-link></li></ul>',
```